# How to check if first item of RecyclerView is visible on the screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is it possible to check if the first or second item of the `RecyclerView` is visible on the screen of the user?

For example when the user scrolls down:

```
  if (first item not visible to user)  { 
      // do something
  }
  else if ( first item is visible){
      // do something
  }
```

What I currently do is I add a listener to my recycler so that when the user scrolls down, it will do something and scroll up.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        if (dy > 0) {
            mAccountLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mDateLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.d("SCROLLINGDOWN","SCROLL");
        } else {
            mAccountLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mDateLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.d("SCROLLINGUP","SCROLL");
        }
    }
});
```

But what I need is to check if the first item is visible or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can find some helper methods in `RecyclerView.LayoutManager`, for example, if you use a `LinearLayoutManager`, check these methods:

```
int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() // Returns the adapter position of the first fully visible view.
int findFirstVisibleItemPosition() // Returns the adapter position of the first visible view.
int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() // Returns the adapter position of the last fully visible view.
int findLastVisibleItemPosition() // Returns the adapter position of the last visible view.
```

See the full docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()).

In your code:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        if (layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() > 0) {
            mAccountLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mDateLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.d("SCROLLINGDOWN","SCROLL");
        } else {
            mAccountLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mDateLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.d("SCROLLINGUP","SCROLL");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i'm sorry, i dont get it :(

Answer (score 7):

```
int firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
if (firstVisiblePosition  == 0) { do your thing )
```

Comment: should i put it inside of my scroll listener?

Comment: Check whatever event works best for you. Just a tip, don't put too many if-statements or actions in the listener because the event is fired multiple times when the user scrolls.

Comment: recyclerview.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() is not working, i'm sorry. what to do.

Comment: I know what you should do, read my reply once again. You should use your layout manager.

Comment: i currently have RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager =
 new LinearLayoutManager(mContext). i cant use findFirstVisibleItemPosition

Comment: You might need to cast. Could you try int firstVisiblePosition = ((LinearLayoutManager)layoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition(); Also, do not use the hungarion notation https://jakewharton.com/just-say-no-to-hungarian-notation/

Comment: i tried doing this but it's not working :   int firstitem  =  ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                    if (firstitem== 0) {
                        Log.d("visible","visible");
                    }

Comment: try to provide some explanation with your answers.

Comment: @AbhishekGarg what explanation do you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
   declare globally LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

and in oncreate use

     layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

use this layoutmanager in recyclerview
   recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        recyclerview.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                //Tocheck if  recycler is on top
                if (layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
//Its at top ..
                    //ie first item is visible
                } else {
             //not visible`enter code here`
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this things..

```
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;// this two line define as global level.
protected int pastVisibleItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
protected void addScrollListener() {
    rvData.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (dy > 0) //check for scroll down
            {
                visibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                pastVisibleItems = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (!isPullingMoreResults) {
                    if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                        if (mHasMoreResultsToPull && !isPullingMoreResults) {
                            isPullingMoreResults = true;
                            pageNumber++;
                            getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i dont understand,  im sorry :(

Comment: Where should i put the gone and visible code part? that i am said in code no have gone and visible part of code.

Comment: if the (n) item is visible. it should visible, else gone.

Answer (score 0):

for avoid lagging and fix bug when user scroll slow or fast

```
   viewBinding.recycler.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
          
    
                    if (recyclerView.scrollState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
                        if (dy > 0) {
                         //scrolled to Bottom of List

                            viewBinding.searchLayout.visibility = View.GONE
    
                        }
                        //if user scroll fast this if handle it
                        if (dy <= 0) {
                        //scrolled to Top of List

                            if (!viewBinding.recycler.canScrollVertically(-1)) {
                              //recycler view is in firstPosition
                                viewBinding.searchLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (dy <= 0) { //if user scroll slow this if handle it
                     //scrolled to Top of List

                          
                        if (!viewBinding.recycler.canScrollVertically(-1)) {
                              //recycler view is in firstPosition
                            viewBinding.searchLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
```