# Is there a OnScrollListener for RecyclerView which is called continuously while Scrolling and not only when the State is changed or scrolling begins?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, scroll

I have a RecyclerView and a Textview above it and I want to update the Textview depending on the first visible element in my Recyclerview. But Recyclerview only has two OnScroll-Listeners `onScrolled` and `onScrollStateChanged`. Both only gets called when a specific state (transition) is reached. Thats why my TextView only gets updated when I start/end scrolling but I want to update my Textview even in between when the scroll is settling.

In Swift this behavior is reached through "scrollViewDidScroll()".

Is there any way to achieve this in Android?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [how-to-check-if-first-item-of-recyclerview-is-visible-on-the-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50983472/how-to-check-if-first-item-of-recyclerview-is-visible-on-the-screen/50983619)

Comment: @PraveenSP No, my question is not about finding the first visible element but getting continuously notified when a scroll is ongoing.

Comment: If I am not wrong onScrolled give information continuously whenever there is a scroll event ...

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I must have made another mistake earlier which made that not work. Thanks.

Comment: No problem...Happy Coding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if(dy > 0) Log.d("db","scrolling up");
            else if(dy < 0) Log.d("db","scrolling dowm");
        }
    });
```